# Cant do HTML, JS local storage buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

My code is not working and I cant find anything that helps me. This is the html:

```
<div class="content-block-title">Your Notes</div>
<div class="list-block">
<div class="item-inner">
  <li>
    <textarea id="notessave">Historical Sites Notes</textarea>
    <textarea id="notesload" readonly>This is where your notes load</textarea>

     <div class="button" id="saveButton" >Save</div> 
     <div class="button" id="loadButton" >Load</div> 
   </li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript is:

```
var buttonSave = document.getElementById('saveButton');

buttonSave.addEventListener('click', function(e){saveNotes()});

var buttonLoad = document.getElementById('loadButton');

buttonLoad.addEventListener('click', function(e){loadNotes()});

function saveNotes()
{
  var save = document.getElementById('notessave');
  localStorage.setItem('notes',save.value);
}

function loadNotes()
{
  document.getElementById('notesload').innerHTML = 
  localStorage.getItem('notes');
}
```

I'm trying to create a button on my page that saves the data from a `textarea`, save it to local storage and then create another button that will load the data back from local storage into another `textarea`.

Comment: Seems to work for the most part https://jsfiddle.net/m0h3vxjL/

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Were are you adding the javascript? It might be running before the page has fully loaded and the buttons are created

Comment: Well, that's a strange behavior you've got here. It works for me too. `Cannot read property 'addEventListener'` means that either `buttonSave` or `buttonLoad` is `null` in your code, but the code is good. Can you show the full HTML to see where the script is loaded?

Comment: The script is loaded on the menu page of my app and is carried across when loading the next page, if that makes sense. Tried reloading it on the page at hand but still not working.

Comment: Well, you should probably try to put the JS code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // put your js here
});`

Comment: @YoannFleuryDev I think it's a little more concise (and accomplishes the same thing) to use `window.onload = function() {/*your code here*/}`